# How to call function of one model in another model in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my StudentsForm model:

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'sname' => 'Name',
            'fill' => ' Date',
        );
    }
```

and in my TeacherForm in my model:

```
 public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'id' => 'ID',
                'tname' => ' Teacher Name',
                'fill' => ' Date',
            );
        }
```

How can I call attributeLabels() of StudentsForm in TeachersForm.
Both models are located in one model

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this

```
$lables = StudentsForm::model()->attributeLabels();
```

`$lables` will be an `array`

```
$lables = array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'sname' => 'Name',
            'fill' => ' Date',
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this by 2 methods.

1. by yii method
2. by using oop

First method.

```
$studentLable = StudentsForm::model()->attributeLabels();
```

Second method.

```
$studentModel = new StudentsForm;

$studentLable = $studentModel->attributeLabels();
```